# Singapore Visa application by mail, included only one photo

Tags: singapore

I am an Indian citizen residing in USA. I submitted Singapore Visa application by mail to VFS which handles Visa applications for the consulate in San Francisco. I forgot to paste photo to my form14a, but included one photo in my packet as mentioned in the checklist at http://www.vfsglobal.com/Singapore/USA/pdf/VFS-checklist.pdf
Would my application be considered incomplete?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s primarily opinion-based and the OP should contact VFS for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

They will likely paste that photo in the form. For sure, you have to call VFS with your application number and get it confirmed.

Comment: Yes. I applied for Singapore visa before and I had provided photo separately.

I also suggested to call VFS and confirm.